# Excel VBA Formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

Hello fellow programmers,

I am currently at work and needed to add some conditions to an existing vba formula. After some dump work trying to bring the excel formula into an vba valid string. I tested it and got the problem, that it always results in `INCORRECT`. I can't find the bug in it. Can some VBA god help me?

### Attention the Formula is a Local one.

### `WENN=IF, ZÄHLENWENN=COUNTIF`

Code below

```
"=WENN(ZÄHLENWENN('Step 3 - Validate your data 2'!I8;""ok"")<4;""INCORRECT"";WENN(ISTFEHLER('Step 3 - Validate your data 2'!D8);""INCORRECT"";WENN('Step 3 - Validate your data 2'!D8=FALSCH;""INCORRECT"";WENN('Step 3 - Validate your data 2'!H8=""special characters are not allowed"";""INCORRECT"";WENN('Step 3 - Validate your data 2'!H8=""Last Name is mandatory"";""INCORRECT"";WENN('Step 3 - Validate your data 2'!H8=""too many characters"";""INCORRECT"";WENN('Step 3 - Validate your data 2'!F8=""special characters are not allowed"";""INCORRECT"";WENN('Step 3 - Validate your data 2'!F8=""too many characters"";""INCORRECT"";" & _
                                                        "WENN('Step 3 - Validate your data 2'!G8=""special characters are not allowed"";""INCORRECT"";WENN('Step 3 - Validate your data 2'!G8=""too many characters"";""INCORRECT"";WENN('Step 3 - Validate your data 2'!E8=""Duplicate"";""INCORRECT"";WENN('Step 3 - Validate your data 2'!C8=""ok"";""CORRECT"";" & _
                                                        "WENN('Step 3 - Validate your data 2'!M8=""ok"";""CORRECT"";WENN('Step 3 - Validate your data 2'!N8=""ok"";""CORRECT"";WENN('Step 3 - Validate your data 2'!Q8=""ok"";""CORRECT"";WENN('Step 3 - Validate your data 2'!P8=""ok"";""CORRECT"";WENN('Step 3 - Validate your data 2'!R8=""ok"";""CORRECT"";" & _
                                                        "WENN('Step 3 - Validate your data 2'!S8=""ok"";""CORRECT"";WENN('Step 3 - Validate your data 2'!T8=""ok"";""CORRECT"";WENN('Step 3 - Validate your data 2'!U8=""ok"";""CORRECT"";WENN('Step 3 - Validate your data 2'!V8=""ok"";""CORRECT"";WENN('Step 3 - Validate your data 2'!W8=""ok"";""CORRECT"";" & _
                                                        "WENN('Step 3 - Validate your data 2'!X8=""ok"";""CORRECT"";WENN('Step 3 - Validate your data 2'!Y8=""ok"";""CORRECT"";WENN('Step 3 - Validate your data 2'!Z8=""ok"";""CORRECT"";WENN('Step 3 - Validate your data 2'!AB8=""ok"";""CORRECT"";WENN('Step 3 - Validate your data 2'!AC8=""ok"";""CORRECT"";" & _
                                                        "WENN('Step 3 - Validate your data 2'!AD8=""ok"";""CORRECT"";WENN('Step 3 - Validate your data 2'!AE8=""ok"";""CORRECT"";WENN('Step 3 - Validate your data 2'!AF8=""ok"";""CORRECT"";WENN('Step 3 - Validate your data 2'!AG8=""ok"";""CORRECT"";WENN('Step 3 - Validate your data 2'!AH8=""ok"";""CORRECT"";" & _
                                                    "WENN('Step 3 - Validate your data 2'!J8=""ok"";""CORRECT"";WENN('Step 3 - Validate your data 2'!K8=""ok"";""CORRECT"";WENN('Step 3 - Validate your data 2'!L8=""ok"";""CORRECT"";WENN('Step 3 - Validate your data 2'!BB8=""ok"";""CORRECT"";""INCORRECT""))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))"
```

Comment: That may be too long for a VBA formula, as there's a limit to the total number of characters.  What are you trying to do here, as there may be a better way to do that formula (`VLOOKUP`/`INDEX/MATCH` perhaps?)

Comment: @BruceWayne it shouldn't be too long, there are longer ones inside the project. Sadly I need to if any of the other formula fields threw an error like: special characters are not allowed.

Comment: @BruceWayne I think I found the error, I am checking for "ok", when I should be checking for the error message

Comment: *there are longer ones inside the project* - time to re-construct the project for ease of maintainability and readability :)